# Is there any efficient way to convert an unary number to a binary number?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

Let those datatypes represent unary and binary natural numbers, respectively:

```
data UNat = Succ UNat | Zero
data BNat = One BNat | Zero BNat | End

u0 = Zero
u1 = Succ Zero
u2 = Succ (Succ Zero)
u3 = Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))
u4 = Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero)))

b0 = End                   //   0
b1 = One End               //   1
b2 = One (Zero End)        //  10
b3 = One (One End)         //  11
b4 = One (Zero (Zero End)) // 100

(Alternatively, one could use `Zero End` as b1, `One End` as b2, `Zero (Zero End)` as b3...)
```

My question is: is there any way to implement the function:

```
toBNat :: UNat -> BNat
```

That works in `O(N)`, doing only one pass through UNat?

Comment: Conversion from unary to any other base is complicated by the fact that none of the target digits can be determined without reading the entire number first.

Comment: To make the question accessible to non-Haskellers, I'd add this equivalent problem. If we have a very long linked list, can we compute its length `N` in time `O(N)`? Note that addition is _not_ considered a constant time operation here, so the trivial approach would only provide `O(N log N)`. (This last part is crucial to the problem, IMHO.)

Comment: Incrementing by 1 has amortized complexity O(1), doesn't it? (Each increment changes an average of 2 digits.)  So just repeating the naive ripple carry increment for each unary digit should have amortized complexity O(N).

Comment: @Carsten Only if you're stupid enough to use a big-endian representation. :)  The LSB should be first, of course.  You can always reverse it at the end of counting digits if you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To increment a binary digit, you have to flip the first zero at the end of your number and all the ones preceding it. The cost of this operation is proportional to the number of 1 at the end of your input (for this your should represent number as right-to-left list, eg. the list [1;0;1;1] codes for 13).

Let a(n) be the number of 1 at the end of n:

```
a(n) = 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 4, ...
```

and let

```
s(k) = a(2^k) + a(2^k+1) + ... + a(2^(k+1)-1)
```

be the sum of elements between two powers of 2. You should be able to convince yourself that s(k+1)=2*s(k) + 1 (with s(0) = 1) by noticing that

```
    a(2^(k+1)) ..., a(2^(k+2) - 1)
```

is obtained by concatenating

```
    a(2^k) + 1, ..., a(2^(k+1) - 1) and   a(2^k), ..., a(2^(k+1) - 1)
```

And therefore, as a geometric series, s(k) = 2^k - 1.

Now the cost of incrementing N times a number should be proportional to

```
    a(0) + a(1) + ... + a(N)
  = s(0) + s(1) + s(2)  + ... + s(log(N)) 
  = 2^0 - 1 + 2^1 -1 + 2^2-1 + ... + 2^log(N) - 1
  = 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + ... + 2^log(N) - log(N) - 1
  = 2^(log(N) + 1) - 1 - log(N) - 1 = 2N - log(N) - 2
```

Therefore, if you take care of representing your numbers from right-to-left, then the naive algorithm is linear (note that you can perform to list reversal and stay linear if you really need your numbers the other way around).

Comment: @Daniel Wagner also has a very simple explanation on why the complexity can be linear below.

Answer (score 10):

I like the other answers, but I find their asymptotic analyses complicated. I therefore propose another answer that has a very simple asymptotic analysis. The basic idea is to implement `divMod 2` for unary numbers. Thus:

```
data UNat = Succ UNat | Zero
data Bit = I | O

divMod2 :: UNat -> (UNat, Bit)
divMod2 Zero = (Zero, O)
divMod2 (Succ Zero) = (Zero, I)
divMod2 (Succ (Succ n)) = case divMod2 n of
    ~(div, mod) -> (Succ div, mod)
```

Now we can convert to binary by iterating `divMod`.

```
toBinary :: UNat -> [Bit]
toBinary Zero = []
toBinary n = case divMod2 n of
    ~(div, mod) -> mod : toBinary div
```

The asymptotic analysis is now pretty simple. Given a number `n` in unary notation, `divMod2` takes O(n) time to produce a number half as big -- say, it takes at most `c*n` time for large enough `n`. Iterating this procedure therefore takes this much time:

```
c*(n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + ...)
```

As we all know, this series converges to `c*(2*n)`, so `toBinary` is also in O(n) with witness constant `2*c`.

Comment: I love that approach because only now it makes sense why the constant would be `2c`.

Comment: Can you just stop yelling at me, though?

Comment: @Viclib Yelling at you? What do you mean?

Comment: @Viclib Oh, hahaha! In that case, you can shut me up by mousing over my image at http://dmwit.com. =D

Comment: Okay... not sure how I feel about this. Looks like you are eating my mouse, does.

Answer (score 5):

If we have a function to increment a `BNat`, we can do this quite easily by running along the `UNat`, incrementing a `BNat` at each step:

```
toBNat :: UNat -> BNat
toBNat = toBNat' End
    where
    toBNat' :: BNat -> UNat -> BNat
    toBNat' c Zero     = c
    toBNat' c (Succ n) = toBNat' (increment c) n
```

Now, this is `O(NM)` where `M` is the worst case for `increment`. So if we can do `increment` in O(1), then the answer is yes.

Here's my attempt at implementing `increment`:

```
increment :: BNat -> BNat
increment = (reverse End) . inc' . (reverse End)
    where
    inc' :: BNat -> BNat
    inc' End      = One End
    inc' (Zero n) = One n
    inc' (One n)  = Zero (inc' n)

    reverse :: BNat -> BNat -> BNat
    reverse c End = c
    reverse c (One n) = reverse (One c) n
```

This implementation is `O(N)` because you have to `reverse` the `BNat` to look at the least significant bits, which gives you `O(N)` overall. If we consider the `BNat` type to represent reversed binary numbers, we don't need to reverse the `BNat`, and, as @augustss says, we have O(1), which gives you O(N) overall.