# Is there any algebraic representation of natural numbers that allow for parallel addition?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, data-structures, parallel-processing, addition

Natural numbers can be represented in **logarithmic space** using a binary representation (here, in little-endian):

```
-- The type of binary numbers; little-endian; O = Zero, I = One
data Bin = O Bin | I Bin | End
```

Addition of `a` and `b` can then be implemented, for example, by calling the `successor` function ([`O(log(N))`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33257360/is-there-any-efficient-way-to-convert-an-unary-number-to-a-binary-number)) `a` times on `b`. The problem with this implementation is that it is inherently sequential. In order to add 2 numbers, `suc` calls are chained in sequence. Other implementations of `add` (such as using carry) suffer from the same issue. It is easy to see that addition couldn't be implemented in parallel with that representation. **Is there any representation of natural numbers, using algebraic datatypes, which takes logarithm space, and on which addition can be done in parallel?**

*Code for illustration:*

```
-- The usual fold  
fold :: Bin -> (t -> t) -> (t -> t) -> t -> t
fold (O bin) zero one end = zero (fold bin zero one end)
fold (I bin) zero one end = one (fold bin zero one end)
fold E zero one end       = end

-- Successor of `Bin` - `O(log(N))`
suc :: Bin -> Bin
suc (O bin) = I bin
suc (I bin) = O (suc bin)
suc E       = E

-- Calls a function `a` times
times :: Bin -> (t -> t) -> t -> t
times a f x     = fold a zero one end f where 
    one bin fs  = fs (bin (fs . fs))
    zero bin fs = bin (fs . fs)
    end fs      = x

-- Adds 2 binary numbers
add :: Bin -> Bin -> Bin
add a b = (a `times` suc) b

-- 1001 + 1000 = 0101
main = print $ add (I (O (O (I E)))) (I (O (O (O E))))
```

Comment: "binary" IS a representation, and it has the problem you mention -- the carry for each bit depends on all the lower-order bits.  So it's difficult to figure out what you want.  A way to add binary numbers with more parallelism (like carry-lookahead adder), or a non-binary representation (like CRT representation) that lets you do addition (and multiplication) in parallel

Comment: @MattTimmermans that is a valid objection, I have edited the question. I hope it make more sense now.

Comment: I second carry-lookahead adders as a way to improve parallelism. There's also a related probabilistic approach: if you sum two bit strings with an initial carry `a+b+carry1 = result + carry2` you can compute `carry2` without looking at `carry1` in the vast majority of cases, i.e. in all cases where `map not a /= b`. So you can produce the output carry in advance and start adding the next bit block without waiting for the previous carry (in most cases).

Comment: "can be done in parallel" is pretty vague, do you have a specific notion in mind?

Comment: I'm thinking in some kind of tree representation like `data Nat = Bin Nat Nat |  Zero | One`, with a mapping to natural numbers, and on which `add : Nat → Nat → Nat` can be implemented in parallel because two branches can be added independently. `add (Bin l r) = _ l _ r _; add Zero = _; add One = _;`... something on those lines is what I have in mind.

Answer (score 4):

There are many parallel adder architectures. An excellent review is given in [Thomas Walker Lynch's master's thesis at the university of Texas at Austin, 1996](https://repositories.lib.utexas.edu/handle/2152/13960). See section 9.1, where he summarizes the worst case path length.

The *Lynch and Swartzlander adder (L&S)* has a worst case path length of 2*ceil(log4(N))+2, where N is that number of bits. The architecture is presented in their paper *[A Spanning Tree Carry Lookahead Adder](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=156535)*.

You can find excellent explanations about many simple architectures by googling "fast adder".

Comment: Great answer. That shows it is possible. Now all is left is translating the technique to ADTs. My naive `Bin` definition can't be parallelized with this strategy since you can't read the `nth` bit of `Bin` in parallel (like you can with a machine bit-vector). I believe some kind of clever binary tree representation could make it work.

Comment: (Why did you remove [this link](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Comb/lookahead.html)?)

Comment: @Viclib: Simply because there are so many excellent links and this is just one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say that each natural number has to have a unique representation. So, here is another option. (I didn't invent it, but I can't remember what it's called, so I had to reconstruct how it works.)

Represent numbers as strings of digits in base 2 like in binary, except that rather than being restricted to the digits 0 and 1, we are additionally allowed to use the digit 2. So for example, the number 2 has two representations, 10 and 2.

To add two numbers represented in this way, just add them digitwise without carrying. Clearly we can do this efficiently in parallel (with a linear size, constant depth circuit). Well, now we have a problem: the resulting number has the right base-2 value, but its digits won't necessarily be 0, 1 or 2, but might be as large as 4.

So let's fix that with the following carry propagation pass: Write each digit of the result as a two-digit binary number where the second digit is 0 or 1, and the first digit can be 0, 1 or 2. (So 0 -> 00, 1 -> 01, 2 -> 10, 3 -> 11, 4 -> 20.) Now "carry" the first digit of each these two-digit numbers to the left, leaving behind the second digit, but without performing any other carrying on the result. For example, if we started with the number

```
 314102    (perhaps from the original problem of computing 212001 + 102101)
```

we perform the sum

```
11       = 3
 01      = 1
  20     = 4
   01    = 1
    00   = 0
     10  = 2
-------
1130110
```

The new number has the same base-2 value, and its digits are now in the range 0 to 3, since they are formed from the sum of a digit that was 0, 1 or 2 and a digit that was 0 or 1. Moreover each digit of the result only depends on the corresponding digit and the digit to its right in the number from the step, so this is implementable by another linear size, constant depth circuit.

This isn't quite good enough, so let's do the same carry propagation pass one more time. Now, 4 is no longer a possible input digit, so the digit that we carry can never be 2, only 0 or 1. So this time the procedure will result in a base 2 representation that uses only the digits 0, 1 and 2, which was what we wanted. In the example from above, the result will be `1210110`. (Of course, any other representation with the same base-2 value would be correct as well.)

(For other combinations of base and maximum digit, you might only need one carry propagation pass. For example if you represent numbers in base 3 using the digits 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4, the largest digit appearing in a sum is 8, so both digits involved in the carry propagation pass will be in the range 0, 1, 2 and their sum will already be at most 4.)

---

Now if you want to do other operations on this representation, such as comparing two numbers for equality, one option is to convert to binary, either serially in linear time, or in parallel by using a fast adder as described in Lior Kogan's answer. In fact, converting this representation to binary is essentially equivalent to the problem of adding numbers in binary, since we can consider a representation like `212001` as a "formal addition" `101000 + 111001`. However, you probably cannot test for equality in this representation in constant depth like you can for binary. I imagine that the "hardness" in this sense of either addition or equality testing is essential given your other constraints, though I don't know for sure.

Comment: These might just be called redundant binary numbers. I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way how to describe parallel addition of natural numbers is this: If you look at the [full adder circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)#Full_adder), it has 3 input bits and it outputs a 2-bit number saying how many of the input bits were 1.
This is also why it's sometimes called [3:2 compressor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)#3:2_compressors). From them we can create a circuit that adds 3 binary numbers in parallel to produce 2 binary numbers. This is also called a [carry-save adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry-save_adder) circuit, because instead of propagating the carry bits, we keep them as another, separate number. Each number is then (redundantly) represented as a pair of binary numbers. And when adding *k* natural numbers, at each step we can reduce triplets to tuples, requiring only *O(log k)* time steps.

But the problem is that if we're only restricted to ADTs, we have a fixed set of constructors, each constructor having a finite number of records. So no matter what, the depth of such a structure will be *O(log n)*. And we have to perform *O(log n)* steps just to traverse the structure.